# How to send unrelated data using jsonapi format

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, json-api

I am trying to build an api following jsonapi specfication [http://jsonapi.org/]. I want to send unrelated data from two different tables. How should I send it. I can send it as below. Is it the right way according to specs? Ideally we should have separate endpoints for such purpose, but I don't want to create separate endpoint due to extra n/w request involved.

```
{
  data: [
    {
      type: "user",
      atrributes: {
        ...
      } 
    },
    {
      type: "company",
      attributes: {
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
 }
```

Also currently I am using ja_serializer [https://github.com/vt-elixir/ja_serializer/] to serialize json. Is there a good to serialize unrelated data from several tables together

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Strictly as JSON-API you can't do that.

Long answer:

## 0) Don't unnecessary complicate your life

Ask yourself if the benefit of avoiding extra request is worth the additional code complexity. If you run your servers on HTTP/2, the additional network overhead will be minimal anyway.

In many cases you fill find pay backs if you keep it simple and separated in future - when you want to do different requests or combine just companies with other type or resources etc.

## 1) Wrap multiple JSON-API responses

But if you really really want JSON-API and single request, maybe what you can do is to wrap 2 JSON-API responses to one. Somethink like this:

```
{
  "responses": [{
     "name": "companies",
     "jsonapi": {"data": ... }
  }, {
     "name": "users",
     "jsonapi": {"data": ... }
  }]
}
```

And then in client you can break these down and use in standard JSON-API libraries as separated resources.

## 2) Try to find common "parent" and use relatoionship from JSON-API

You say these resources are unrelated, but if you want to request them together they must have something in common. Perhaps it is something like "organization" (you) which has many companies and users?

## 3) Other options

JSON-API is meant to standradize object to REST mapping. If you don't need it, JSON-API is not fit for your purpose.

Maybe something like GraphQL would fit it better for you. Or just go for your proprietary format.

Comment: Why is it not possible according to the spec? `data` key can be an array of resource objects, with the only requirement that each one has `id` and `type`. http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects